# How to add vba code in ms access

Tags: vba, ms-access

[image: vba]

I am using web app, and I want to add the vba code after I update the Open date.
but when I click after update, I can just add macro, there is no vba code options.
I google it but I can't find any property sheet even I click right. How can I add the vba code there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. Access web apps don't support VBA code. There is no way to work around that, to my knowledge.

You can always migrate to a normal database.

Comment: oh..after the Open date is updated, I want to make a yes/no messagebox so if the user choose yes, I want to  execute some actions.,. is there anyways I could do that?

Comment: You should be able to, but my experience with macros in Access Web App is limited (since I normally always use VBA). But you should be able to use an If statement in the macro, and use something like this: `MsgBox("Message";4;"My Title")=6` (4 = vbYesNo 6 = vbYes) (edit: well, it works in a macro in the desktop version, don't have a testing WebApp available)

Comment: I tried to but how can I include MessageBox in the if loop? When I try to write if(MsgBox() == 6), they don't recognize the MsgBox.

Comment: Well, I feared that, it means MsgBox is a desktop-only function. The alternative is making a form that looks like a message box, and binding macros to its buttons.

Comment: There is no form looks like a messagebox..yes but I think that is the best options...Thank you!!